# Docker exec in bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I'm creating dynamically docker containers via bash script:

```
while getopts ":s:d:h" opt; do
    case $opt in
        s)
            for i in $(seq $2 $END); 
                do 
                    docker run -dit --name=app_client_$i -d app:client
                    docker exec -d app_client_$i $app_start
            done
            ;;
...
```

The docker container starts fine, but the `docker exec` command caused problems. When I try (without the `-d`):

```
docker exec app_client_$i $app_start
```

The application inside the docker container starts fine - but I'm attached to this docker container. I want to start the app inside the docker container in the background, so I use the `-d` parameter:

```
docker exec -d app_client_$i $app_start
```

With that the app doesn't start inside the docker container. What I am missing?

Comment: What do you get from docker logs app_client_$i?

Comment: I've already tried that. I get nothing from the logs. If I type `docker logs app_client_$1` there is no output.

Comment: The value of `$app_start` is a java call with the java interpreter.

Comment: Weird thing in your `docker run -itd`  which should be either a daemon or interactive, but not both, and `docker exec` should not be with -d, See supervisor, runit, daemontools or s6 you want to launch several processes in a container

Comment: Okay, tried it without the `-i` parameter inside the run command and also tried it with the quoting variables like `"app_client_$i" "$app_start"`. Both do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, got it (facepalm):

With the `docker -d` you're going to start the process INSIDE the container in the background. So my app was already running inside the container, but in the background.

Cheers!